# Command 'pip --disable-pip-version-check install returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, libraries

**I have the follow code:**

```
%pip install --upgrade https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays/tarball/beta
```

**Got this error, is there anything I can do, or just wait to the librarie get update:**

```
  CalledProcessError: Command 'pip --disable-pip-version-check install --upgrade https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays/tarball/beta' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. What versions of python, pip, and holidays are you current using?